# Solution check: How many persons saw both performances?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

> **Problem:** One evening two performances was given. There was 600 persons who could see them both, but only 80 saw the first one, and 125 saw the other one. 450 persons missed both of the performances. How many persons saw both?

**My solution:** We get the following information: 80 people see the first performance and 125 sees the second one. 205 persons sees the performance totally. We know that 150 persons sees one performance. Therefore, 205 - 150 = 55 persons sees both performances.

Am I thinking correctly? I have no access to any solutions manual.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

$$
|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|=80+125-(600-450)=55\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible for you to explain your calculation a little bit more in detail for a beginner in mathematics? I have just begun learning about sets.

Comment: @ಠಠ: (nice name :-) It's basically what you already wrote in the question. Consider a [Venn diagram](https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/blog/2017Q3/Venn-diagram-symbols-and-notation/VDAIntersectsB.png). $|A|+|B|$ counts each viewer at least once, but it counts those who viewed both performances twice. $|A\cap B$ counts each viewer exactly once. Thus if we subtract it, that leaves only the viewers who viewed both performance, counted only once.